# Babel ES6 unable to export function called new or delete

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Babel and ESLint are throwing parsing errors when i try to export a function with the name "new" or "delete".

```
export function new () {}
export function delete () {}
```

Why is this happening? Is this a bug or is this not plausible because of babel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well `new` and `delete` are reserved words of JavaScript language. So they are not valid names for function.

Comment: Thank you i totally forgot that :D

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a delete function at the root of your module's file but yes, you can export a delete function in your module. You give the function a non reserved name and you give it the correct alias when you export it.

```
function deleteFunc() {
    // ...
}
export { deleteFunc as delete }
```